# Start multiple tasks in parallel and wait for them in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing

How do I execute some tasks in parallel in batch script and wait for them?

```
command1;

# command3, command4 and command5 should execute in sequence say task1
# command6, command7 and command8 should execute in sequence say task2
# both task1 and task2 should run independently

command3; command4; command5 | command6; command7; command8;

# should execute only after the above parallel tasks are completed

command9;
```

As a proof of concept I tried something like but it is not working:

```
echo "Starting"
start /wait wait20.bat   
start /wait wait40.bat 
echo "Finishing"
```

`wait20.bat` looks like:

```
echo "starting 20 seconds job"
timeout 20
echo "finishing 20 seconds job"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657254/in-windows-batch-loop-how-to-wait-for-spawned-processes-to-complete-before-cont/47657549#47657549)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for parallel batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577442/waiting-for-parallel-batch-scripts)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43762349/778560) the simplest way to do that:

```
command1

(
   start "task1" cmd /C "command3 & command4 & command5"
   start "task2" cmd /C "command6 & command7 & command8"
) | pause

command9
```

Further details in *the comments* below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33586872/778560).

Comment: This is so elegant! However, I have a doubt here. if I just do a `start task1`, it does it in the background without monitoring it. So what part of this code actually does the important part of waiting for the background tasks to complete? Is it the `()`, `|` or `pause`? I read the explanation in the comment but it talks about `set /P`.

Comment: Is the pipe `|` combined with any command that read an input from stdin, like `pause` or `set /P`. Such a command will wait until the `start` command send an output (that will never happen) _or_ the background process ends...

Comment: Also, if you are interleaving `timeout` commands with the `start` ones (to stagger the parallel execution), make sure to add `>nul` at the end of each `timeout` statement otherwise the `pause` will not work.

Comment: @Burhan: I don't see how a `timeout` command could be useful in this case... Of course, if you insert _any command_ that output anything to the console, it would break the `pause` (not just the `timeout` command).

Comment: @Aacini I had a bunch of build processes that I wanted to run in parallel, but they shared one key file. If all the processes started at the exact same time, only one of them would get a lock on the key file and rest would fail. However, staggering them by a second using `timeout` allowed enough time for every process to read the key file and release the lock before the next one would try locking it again.

Comment: @Aacini Also, thanks for the clarification on any output breaking `pause`, I suspected as much but wasn't 100% sure since I only tried `timeout`. Maybe you can add that to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example how it can be done with tasklist and process window titles:

**launcher.cmd**

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,5) do start "worker%%a" cmd /c worker.cmd & timeout /t 1 >nul
:loop
timeout /t 2 >nul
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /fo csv | findstr /i "worker" >nul && goto :loop
echo Workers finished
```

**worker.cmd**

```
@echo off
set /a wait=2 + ( %RANDOM% %% 5 ) 
echo waiting for %wait%...
timeout /t %wait% >nul
echo I'm done!
timeout /t 2 >nul
```

I'm using `tasklist /v /fo csv` to get titles.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to not display `tasklist` and `timeout` commands in the console?

Comment: Just redirect output to nul: `timeout /t NN >nul`, `findstr /i ... >nul`

Comment: That still shows the `timeout` command, just not the **output**!

Comment: Strange... I've just checked, and it is showing nothing for me. I've updated my post with `> nul`

Comment: This method waste CPU time repeatedly executing `tasklist` and `findstr` commands until parallel processes ends. An [event driven method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49051876/778560) is more efficient and simpler...

Comment: @Aacini, how much CPU does it waste running every two seconds?

Comment: @wolfrevokcats, the point Aacini is making is that it that the other approach is event-driven. It just wakes up the process when it is ready which is always cleaner than doing a poll.

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is that the main batch waits indefinitely for others to finish, while polling approach allows you to check for some timeout. Otherwise, it is a nice trick to have.