# nesting multiple .cmd files with prerequisites running in a certain order

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing

I'm having trouble figuring out the logic behind this. I have 11 `.cmd` files that need to run in a certain order. 5 of them can start simultaneously, the next 5 are directly dependent on the corresponding of the first five, and the last file is dependent on the second set of five to be run.

Image of workflow:
[image: IMAGE OF WORKFLOW]

- Step 1 is to start `QAQC` processes 1-5.
- Step 2 is to start the corresponding `CONVERT` processes for each `QAQC` process as it finishes.
- Step 3 is to merge all outputs once all 5 `CONVERT` processes are finished.

I imagine I need to make a `.cmd` or `.bat` file for each and then call the 5 files in one file.

**`file1.cmd`:**

```
 call QAQC1
 call CONVERT1
```

**`file2.cmd`:**

```
call QAQC2
call CONVERT2
```

and so on...

And the final file would be something like:

**`FINAL_FINAL.cmd`:**

```
start "QAQC1.cmd" QAQC1.cmd
start "QAQC2.cmd" QAQC2.cmd
start "QAQC3.cmd" QAQC3.cmd
start "QAQC4.cmd" QAQC4.cmd
start "QAQC5.cmd" QAQC5.cmd
```

I'm still unclear if this is correct or how I would make all of these steps finish before I make a call to the final file that merges everything together and requires all 10 other files to complete. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it true that step 2 (`CONVERT`) has to wait until step 1 (`QAQC`) is completed, meaning that all five `QAQC` processes have to be finished before the first `CONVERT` process begins? Also am I wondering how you pass data from the `QAQC` steps to the `CONVERT` steps…

Comment: Perhaps it would be possible to use one batch file `QAQC` and to configure it using five different sets of command line arguments rather than five similar files, given that then intrinsic function is the same for all `QAQC` processes, and the same for `CONVERT`…

Comment: Perhaps this thread deals with a quite similar situation: [Start multiple tasks in parallel and wait for them in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49050611)

Comment: @aschipfl - Not all QAQC processes have to finish before the first CONVERT process. Just the corresponding one. So if QAQC3 finishes before QAQC1 or QAQC2, then CONVERT 3 can run. Each CONVERT step is only dependent on its corresponding QAQC step. All QAQC processes can begin simultaneously. 

Data is written out to a feature class at each step for both record keeping purposes and to send data back to original owner (and because my boss requested it this way). The red lines show each steps dependency.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%a in (1,1,5) do (
  set /a x=!random! %% 10
  >QAQC%%a.cmd (
    echo @echo QAQC%%a
    echo @timeout !x!
  )
  >CONVERT!%%a.cmd (
    echo @echo CONVERT%%a
    echo @timeout !x!
  )
)
echo @echo merge running >merge.cmd
echo @timeout 3 >>merge.cmd
REM ignore anything before this line; it just creates a test environment

@echo off
echo wait for qaqcX and convertX to finish...
( start cmd /c "qaqc1.cmd & convert1.cmd"
  start cmd /c "qaqc2.cmd & convert2.cmd"
  start cmd /c "qaqc3.cmd & convert3.cmd"
  start cmd /c "qaqc4.cmd & convert4.cmd"
  start cmd /c "qaqc5.cmd & convert5.cmd"
) | pause >nul
call merge.cmd
echo done.
```

Comment: Can you explain the first section to me? What exactly is it doing? I ran the code without it and it ran just the same, is it necessary? Either way, this worked perfectly. Thank you!!!

Comment: The part before the `REM`? It just generates some fake `QAQC*.cmd` and `convert*.cmd` files plus a fake `merge.cmd` to have something to run.