# Send folder to s3 bucket, but do not copy the folder structure

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-s3

I want to send a recursive folder to amazon.

the folder:
folder

```
└───FOLDER
    ├───SUBFOLDER
            |
            |__ file1.jpg
            |
            |__ file2.jpg
    ├───SUBFOLDER(2)
            |
            |__ file3.jpg
            |
            |__ file4.jpg
```

for this use:

```
asw s3 cp /folder s3://mybucket/folder_destination --recursive
```

but it arrives at the bucket with the same folder structure in the bucket.

my wish is that it reaches the bucket with this structure:

```
└───BUCKET
        ├───folder_destination
                |
                |__ file1.jpg
                |
                |__ file2.jpg
                |
                |__ file3.jpg
                |
                |__ file4.jpg
```

I tested this bat:

```
pushd C:\Users\user\Desktop\FOLDER
for /r %%a in (*.jpg) do (
       aws s3 cp  "%%a" "s3://bucket/Test/%%~nxa"
   )
   popd
```

he does what I want but very slowly.

```
for (File f : arquivos) {
            System.out.println(f);
            String fileObjKeyName = "Test" + f.toString().split("/")[f.toString().split("/").length - 1];


            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, f);
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            //metadata.addUserMetadata("title", "someTitle");
            request.setMetadata(metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(request);
        }
```

slow too

is there any way to send them quickly without the folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

Quickest and simplest would be to first copy all of the individual files from the multiple subfolders to a new, temporary folder, and then `aws s3 sync` that folder up to S3, then wipe the temporary folder.

Or perhaps you could [run commands concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050611/start-multiple-tasks-in-parallel-and-wait-for-them-in-windows).