# How to make a batch file wait for all processes of another call to finish before continuing

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, cmd, ffmpeg

The idea of this script is to take a (lecture) video, split it into smaller pieces, remove the silence for each one, and merge them back together, for increased performance, since the silence-removing script does not scale that well for larger videos.

The 3 batch scripts below work perfectly when started manually after eachother, but when trying to launch them from a single *.bat* file, I can't prevent them from starting at the same time, which creates errors at the merging stage.

These are the 3 batch files:

1. *split.bat*
2. *startall.bat*
3. *merge.bat*

*Split.bat* creates 10 minute long segments, afterwards, *startall.bat* starts one [Video-Remove-Silence](https://github.com/excitoon/video-remove-silence) task for every segment. At the end, *merge.bat* creates one single mp4 file with all the segments.

*split.bat* does the following:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:10:00 -f segment out%%03d.mp4
exit
```

*startall.bat*:

```
start start000.bat
start start001.bat
start start002.bat
start start003.bat
...
```

The *start000.bat* call looks like this:

```
python video-remove-silence out000.mp4 --linear 0.0005
exit
```

And *merge.bat*:

```
:: Create File List
for %%i in (*_result.mp4) do echo file '%%i'>> mylist.txt
:: Concatenate Files
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy shortened.mp4

del "C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\download\mylist.txt"
del "C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\download\out*.mp4"
exit
```

When trying either *call*, or *start /wait*, errors occur due to simultaneous execution:

```
START /wait split.bat
START /wait startall2.bat
START /wait merge.bat
```

So basically my question is, how can I call these 3 scripts and prevent *merge.bat* from starting, until all processes inside *startall.bat* have finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the method stated at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49051876/778560), that is, your main Batch file could be this one:

```
rem Split:
call split.bat

rem Start all and wait for all to terminate
(
start start000.bat
start start001.bat
start start002.bat
start start003.bat
...
) | pause

rem Merge:
call merge.bat
```

Comment: There were some minor issues with the *exit* statements at the end of the separate batch files, I removed those, and now it works exacly as intended - perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that you said you'd done this using `call` already, I do not believe that doing so should have caused you the issue you're reporting. You should have used `Call` everywhere you'd used `start`, and removed the `exit` from the end of each, *(you could also change those to `exit /b` or `goto :EOF` if needed)*:

---

*split.bat*:

```batch-file
@ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:10:00 -f segment out%%03d.mp4
```

*startall.bat*:

```batch-file
@Call start000.bat
@Call start001.bat
@Call start002.bat
@Call start003.bat
...
```

The *start000.bat* call looks like this:

```batch-file
@python video-remove-silence out000.mp4 --linear 0.0005
```

*merge.bat*:

```batch-file
@Rem Create File List
@(For %%I In (*_result.mp4) Do @Echo file '%%I') > mylist.txt
@Rem Concatenate Files
@ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy shortened.mp4
@Del /Q out*.mp4 mylist.txt
```

Execution:

```batch-file
@Call split.bat
@Call startall2.bat
@Call merge.bat
```