# Write a batch (.bat) file that can execute one by one and at once more than one commands

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need to write the batch file that does the following task
I have many commands some commands need to execute at once and some commands need to execute if some command completed.

Like this, I have the command that needs to execute first

```
 start cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl categorylink
```

when above finishes I need to run these below three commands at once. Because these three commands depending on the output of the first command

```
start cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl abercrombiecomtw_kids_links
start cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl abercrombiecomtw_other_link
start cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl abercrombiecomtw_men_links
```

when above three finishes then I need to run this command. Because this command depending on the output of the above three commands

```
start cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl abercrombiecomtw -a tot_div=3 -a div=1
```

for now, all are written in different three batches(.bat) files I want to write one file that does all the things.

I have tried to google it but I was not able to get it because I do not know more about batch files except some basics like above that I have also searched.

Comment: for your three parallel commands, you need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657549/2152082)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `START` command for the first program you want to run.  I assume you want the next three commands to run in parallel.  So you can do something like this.

```
cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl categorylink

(
start cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl abercrombiecomtw_kids_links
start cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl abercrombiecomtw_other_link
start cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl abercrombiecomtw_men_links
)| set /p .=

cmd.exe /c scrapy crawl abercrombiecomtw -a tot_div=3 -a div=1
```

The pipe to set /p makes the execution block wait until all three are finished.