# Waiting for eight parallel batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, locking

I have like 0 experience with coding batch files and I'm actually refering to an older post
"[Waiting for parallel batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577442/waiting-for-parallel-batch-scripts)", and to the answer of *dbenham*.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "lock=%temp%\wait%random%.lock"

:: Launch one and two asynchronously, with stream 9 redirected to a lock file.
:: The lock file will remain locked until the script ends.
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%1" one.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%2" two.bat

:Wait for both scripts to finish (wait until lock files are no longer locked)
1>nul 2>nul ping /n 2 ::1
for %%N in (1 2) do (
  ( rem
  ) 9>"%lock%%%N" || goto :Wait
) 2>nul

::delete the lock files
del "%lock%*"

:: Launch three and four asynchronously
start "" cmd /c three.bat
start "" cmd /c four.bat
```

His answer works fine, but I would like to adapt his solution to run not 2 files simultaneously but 8, and after that another 8 and so on...

Can someone help me?

What I tried so far is this (for 3 blocks of 8 batch files each)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "lock=%temp%\wait%random%.lock"

:: Launch 8 files asynchronously, with stream 9 redirected to a lock file.
:: The lock file will remain locked until the script ends.
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%1" one.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%2" two.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%3" three.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%4" four.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%5" five.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%6" six.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%7" seven.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%8" eight.bat

:Wait for all scripts to finish (wait until lock files are no longer locked)
1>nul 2>nul ping /n 2 ::1
for %%N in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) do (
  ( rem
  ) 9>"%lock%%%N" || goto :Wait
) 2>nul

::delete the lock files
del "%lock%*"

:: Launch 8 files asynchronously, with stream 9 redirected to a lock file.
:: The lock file will remain locked until the script ends.
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%1" nine.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%2" ten.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%3" eleven.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%4" twelve.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%5" thirteen.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%6" fourteen.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%7" fifteen.bat
start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%8" sixteen.bat

:Wait for all scripts to finish (wait until lock files are no longer locked)
1>nul 2>nul ping /n 2 ::1
for %%N in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) do (
  ( rem
  ) 9>"%lock%%%N" || goto :Wait
) 2>nul

::delete the lock files
del "%lock%*"

:: Launch three and four asynchronously
start "" cmd /c seventeen.bat
start "" cmd /c eighteen.bat
start "" cmd /c nineteen.bat
start "" cmd /c twenty.bat
start "" cmd /c twenty-one.bat
start "" cmd /c twenty-two.bat
start "" cmd /c twenty-three.bat
start "" cmd /c twenty-four.bat
```

But it doesn't seem to work right. Normaly a block of eight batch files will be completed after max. 3h but I waited almost 24h and he seems to be stuck in the first block...

**Critical Info:** When a batch file (or Job) is executed a "cmd" window opens for like 5 seconds, closes and an other programm starts which is doing the actual job of calculations for max. 3h. I looked into the Task Manager and what happens is, 3 processes are started. "standard.exe" and "eliT_DriverLM.exe" after like 20 sec and "python.exe" after 5 sec. Since the process is finished when this 3 processes are no longer running (not showing up in the Task Manager anymore), the programm should wait for the for at least the "standard.exe" to terminate.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far to achieve your goal? please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] of your attempts!

Comment: There are *two* asynchronous calls `start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%1" one.bat` and `start "" cmd /c 9>"%lock%2" two.bat`; simply write *eight* lines of this syntax pattern. Moreover, there is a code snippet of _wait until **two** lock files are no longer locked_. To wait until **eight** lock files are no longer locked, use `for %%N in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) do (`…

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44697124/2152082) and a [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657549/2152082) using another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q57071663.txt"
SET "lockfilename=%temp%\LOCK#_"

:: BLOCKSIZE - if positive, run in blocks of this size.
:: If negative, run max this number of parallel jobs

SET /a blocksize=-5

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=|" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%b"=="" (SET "jobname="&SET "jobinstr=%%a") ELSE (SET "jobname=%%a"&SET "jobinstr=%%b")
  CALL :sub
)
GOTO :EOF

:sub
SET /a absblocksize=blocksize
IF %blocksize% gtr 0 GOTO blockmode
SET /a absblocksize=-blocksize
:blockmode
FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,%absblocksize%) DO IF NOT EXIST "%lockfilename%_%%c" SET "lock=%lockfilename%_%%c"&GOTO release
:: No vacant spots, so block complete. Wait for ALL to finish
:blockwait
CALL :wait1
IF %blocksize% gtr 0 IF EXIST "%lockfilename%_*" (GOTO blockwait) ELSE (GOTO blockmode)
GOTO blockmode


:release
ECHO.>"%lock%"
START "%jobname%" CMD /c "call %jobinstr%&DEL "%lock%""

GOTO :eof

:wait1
timeout /t 1 >NUL 2>NUL
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q57071663.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

`%lockfile%` is used temporarily and is a filename of your choosing.

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

The contents of `q57071663.txt` are, for my demo,

> Job 1   | q57071663_sub.bat 12
>   Job 2   | q57071663_sub.bat 4
>   Job 3   | q57071663_sub.bat 15
>   Job 4   | q57071663_sub.bat 2
>   Job 5   | q57071663_sub.bat 
>   Job 6   | q57071663_sub.bat 
>   Job 7   | q57071663_sub.bat 
>   Job 8   | q57071663_sub.bat 
>   Job 9   | q57071663_sub.bat 6
>   Job11   | q57071663_sub.bat 12
>   Job12   | q57071663_sub.bat 4
>   Job13   | q57071663_sub.bat 15
>   Job14   | q57071663_sub.bat 2
>   Job15   | q57071663_sub.bat 
>   Job16   | q57071663_sub.bat 
>   Job17   | q57071663_sub.bat 
>   Job18   | q57071663_sub.bat 
>   Job19   | q57071663_sub.bat 6

Each line is an optional job name, a separator (I chose `|`, obviously) and the command to be executed by `start...`

and `q57071663_sub.bat` is simply

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "delay=%1"
:: IF no delay defined, random 3..19 secs
IF NOT DEFINED delay SET /a delay=3+(%RANDOM% %% 17)
timeout /t %delay% >NUL 2>NUL
```

ie. delay for (argument) seconds, or 3 to 19 if no argument provided.

As for the main routine, the `for/f` splits each line from the file using the `|` separator, and assigns the two parts to `jobname` and `jobinstr`, then executes the subroutine `:sub`.

The subroutine calculates the absolute value of `blocksize` and looks for a missing lockfile. If it finds a lockfile missing in the range, `lock` gets the lock filename and `release` sets a lockfile and starts the job, appending an instruction to delete the lockfile when the job terminates.

if there are no vacant slots available, we wait. If `blocksize` is greater than 0, then we may proceed to the next block if there are no remaining lockfiles, otherwise we wait. If `blocksize` is negative, then we simply try again.

So - if `blocksize` is positive, this would run all of the jobs in the file `n` at a time, waiting until each block of `n` is finished before starting the next block. If `blocksize` is negative, then we run `n` jobs in parallel, starting the next job in the list when any job terminates. This runs `n` jobs at all times.

---

Complete revision in the light of comments and critical information now included in question.

It would appear that the actual requirement is that at most 8 instances of `standard.exe` are running in parallel.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q57071663_c.txt"

SET /a blocksize=5

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "jobinstr=%%a"
 CALL :sub
)
GOTO :EOF

:sub
:: Wait 30 secs (29 + 1) to ensure last-started job is  active
timeout /t 5 >NUL 2>NUL
:delay1
timeout /t 1 >NUL 2>NUL

:: Count #times critical .exe is in tasklist

SET /a active=0
:: FOR /f %%c IN ('tasklist^|findstr /b "standard.exe"^|find /c "standard.exe"' ) DO SET active=%%c
FOR /f %%c IN ('tasklist/v^|findstr /b "cmd.exe"^|find /c "q57071663"' ) DO SET active=%%c
ECHO %active% instances active
IF %active% geq %blocksize% GOTO delay1

START "%jobinstr%" CMD /c "call %jobinstr%"

GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q57071663_c.txt` containing the same job-data as above, **except** that the job-name and delimiter are removed.

I used a `blocksize` of 5 for testing. In OP's application, substitute `8`

So - read each line of job-instructions to `%%a` and thence to `jobinstr` and call the subroutine `SUB`.

First thing to do in `sub` is to wait 30 secs (I used 6 sec for my testing) - this is just to ensure that the last-started job has created its instance of `standard.exe`

Then count the active `standard.exe` instances. I've commented-out the line for `standard.exe` and left in my test command, which requires both `cmd.exe` and `q57071663` to be on the same `tasklist` line to indicate an instance of interest.

If there are the required number of instances already active, delay 1 second and try again.

Otherwise, start the required job.

Comment: Okay I think I forgot to mention something. 
When a batch file (or Job) is executed a "cmd" window opens for like 5 seconds, closes and an other programm starts which is doing the actual job of calculations for max. 3h. 
I looked into the Task Manager and what happens is, 3 processes are started. "standard.exe" and "eliT_DriverLM.exe" after like 20 sec and "python.exe" after 5 sec. Since the process is finished when this 3 processes are no longer running, is there a way to change your code so it checks after some delay time for lets say "python.exe"?

Comment: @Kuba: that's critical info, that should be in the question itself.

Comment: The crucial issue is detecting the termination of the process. Is there a way of definitively identifying the three subsidiary processes relative to the batch that started them? Does the `python` process always terminate as the last of the three?

Comment: @Stephan your absolutely right I edited my question, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @Magoo As far as I know they all terminate at the same time. The thing is that the "python.exe" starts first (after like 5 seconds) but the "standard.exe" (starts after like 20 seconds) is the actual process with the most RAM usage. And as far as I know the "standard.exe" is the actual programm runing the calculations. So I would want the programm to run only eight "standard.exe" at the same time since the computer cant handle more.

Comment: @Magoo Thank you, it works like a charm. You Sir are a real life-saver!